# Why ansible is not able to ping for locally?

Tags: ansible, devops, ansible-2.x, ansible-facts

Without writing ansible-playbook Why ansible is not able to ping locally ?

Problem:-

I have taken 1 ec2 instance and the IP of ec2 is "52.15.160.250". I installed ansible in it. Inside the inventory file [/etc/ansible/hosts] i have taken

> [localhost]
>
> 52.15.160.250

Then [visudo description](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3wxG0.jpg)

I tried to ping local host

> ansible -m ping all

or

> ansible -m ping 52.15.160.250

I am getting the following error

[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XmE3D.jpg)

Comment: Your current user ssh key is not authorized on the remote host.

Comment: Just to avoid confusion: _ansible_ ping **is not** _ICMP_ ping. Ansible ping requires ssh access to the remote machine + python installed on the host.

Comment: @Zeitounator my host and controller machine is same. I wanted to ping the same machine where the ansible is installed.

Answer (score 1):

try adding like this:

```
[localhost]

52.15.160.250 ansible_connection=local
```

this way, it would not attempt over ssh rather it would go by local connection.